# x86 Assembly (AT&T): How to use advanced indexing to set a specific section in memory

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att, addressing-mode

I am trying to set the second byte of the content marked by the label `variable` to the content of the EAX register through advanced indexing. When I execute the code below:

```
movl %eax, 2(variable)
```

I receive the following error:

> **Error: junk `(variable)' after expression**

Is there a way for me to accomplish moving the content of the EAX register into the second byte of variable?

Comment: But note that EAX is 4 bytes wide;  you can't store it into a single byte.  So you'd be storing it to the 4 bytes *starting* at `memoizationMatrix+2` if you got the syntax right, `mov %eax, memoizationMatrix+2`   Also, that's not "advanced" indexing, just a simple `[disp32]` absolute addressing mode with no base register.  Also no index register involved.

Comment: You put a symbol name where only registers can go.  Look at compiler output for `global_array[1] = 1` or something to see the right addressing-mode syntax.